# AJAX Call returns JSON, how to render properly formatted data

Tags: jquery, css, json, html

I am trying to figure out how to format JSON in a better way that I am.

I am using form of javascript like this,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(e) {   
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://www.domain.ca/classes/brain.php?a=select',
        crossDomain: true,
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',

        beforeSend: function() {
        },

        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            $('.pageLoaded').html(data.name +' <br />'+ data.email);
        },

        error: function(responseText) {
            alert('Error: '+ responseText.toString());  
        }
    });
});
</script>
<div data-role="content" class="pageLoaded"></div>
```

But I would like to be able to have a better way to format how the display looks. Perhaps calling a template file?

I can only use HTML + CSS + Javascript... is there any possibilities, or do I have to do what I am doing here?

Comment: JSON's just data... how you format it is entirely up to you.

Comment: Yeah I realize, I just don't like using Javascript to format my rendered display as much... I would like to use it direct in HTML reference...

Comment: if you've got control over the server generating the json, you can include formatted html as well as the raw data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For simple html as  `name + <LINE BREAK> + email`, what you are already doing shuold be fine.

If the HTML gets complex then [jQuery.template](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.template/) is your friend.

For the above situation an example would be:

1) Add a script tag with the html layout you want to generate:

```
<script id="nameTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
   ${name} 
   <br />
   ${email}
</script>
```

2) Change your ajax success handler to:

```
 $( "#nameTemplate" ).tmpl( data).appendTo(".pageLoaded")
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into the jQuery templating plugins?

https://github.com/jquery/jquery-tmpl

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.template/

Answer (score 0):

You can set html inside that div something like this . Although jquery template option suggested seems to be better option.

```
 <div data-role="content" class="pageLoaded">
    <div id="name"></div>
    <div id="email"></div>
    </div>
```

style this as you want with css and in javascript do this

```
 success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
          $("#name").val(data.name);
///other fields
        },
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this

http://scriptble.com/2011/01/underscore-js-templates/

Answer (score 0):

If it's very simple data, don't complicate your life. That's good way of doing it.

If you really want to do templating, check this question:

[What Javascript templating engine do you recommend?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/552934/what-javascript-templating-engine-do-you-recommend)